# Making Slide Show by CSS3 Animation

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, css-animations, fadeout

Have a look at this picture:
http://oi43.tinypic.com/5cdm5g.jpg

This is my idea to design an slide show, which each slide can be a div tag and congaing some text or image and the small behind slide is the next one which is a bit transparent and when the user press the space bar or click somewhere the top slide fades out and the next one moves to forward and replaces, then another slide replace as the next one.
I know it is possible by JS, but what about CSS3? I know I have to put code here, but I have just started and do not know where to start. It would be great if some one help me and gives me some hints.

Comment: What you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best resource I have found for CSS3 questions is http://css-tricks.com/

This is another good resource and is updated regularly by the owner. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com

It will be some advanced CSS3 techniques you'll be using such as transitions, transforms etc..

Good luck